# How to calculate the similarity(0%-99%) of two polylines in Python

Tags: python, geometry, compare, polyline

Both two polylines contains a set of geo positions(like 38.663610000000006,-121.29237), the total number of position for each polylines are different.

How to calculate the similarity(0%-99%) of two polylines in Python?

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the similiary between two lines you can try to use the [Fréchet distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distance).

The `shapely` library provides the [`frechet_distance`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.frechet_distance.html#shapely.frechet_distance) function and its documentation reports the following example:

```py
from shapely import LineString
line1 = LineString([(0, 0), (100, 0)])
line2 = LineString([(0, 0), (50, 50), (100, 0)])
distance = frechet_distance(line1, line2)
```

As you can see the lines are defined by a different number of points. Then, if you need a percentage you can simply normalize the distance value using a reference distance relevant for this problem.